# Write the shortest text getter/setter on an element for the DOM

Tags: code-golf, javascript

Just like jQuery's `$.fn.text`, write one or two functions that can get and set the text on an element.

You can't use `textContent` or `innerText`, and even less `innerHTML`.

Plain javascript. No DOM library. It has to work on major browsers. (No need to care about old IE.)

Shortest code wins.

Enjoy!

Comment: is function name going to be counted towards the total?

Comment: Yep. I should be able to put your function in my page and use it right away. But it should be the same limitation for everyone, so it's not like it's unfair to anyone.

Comment: So, one letter function names. Got it.

Comment: @Shmiddty Also, not having the function declaration would be unfair to people wanting to use recursion.

Answer (score 4):

### JavaScript (167)

```
function t(e,h,f){if(h||h==''){while(f=e.lastChild)e.removeChild(f);e.appendChild(document.createTextNode(h))}h=e.data||'';for(c in f=e.childNodes)h+=t(f[c]);return h}
```

Usage :

```
var textContent = t(yourElement); // get the text content
t(yourElement, ''); // clear
t(yourElement, newText); // sets a new text
```

Note that there is no pollution of the global namespace

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/ekusan/8/edit), with a multi-level DOM tree and a few tests

Comment: `if('split' in h)`

Comment: @Shmiddty That would force the function user to pass something not `undefined`.

Comment: The code golf SE counter reports 175 characters, not 218. Why is it so?

Comment: @JanDvorak where's this counter ? It's my first time here...

Comment: @dystroy http://stackapps.com/questions/2048/code-golf-userscript-enhancement-pack

Comment: There's a formatting problem : if you edit my answer you see a bigger code...

Comment: Hint that other people can use: `data` is shorter than `nodeValue` :-). Can you post the non-golfed version too?

Comment: Well... As I have no makefile to golf it, I don't have any non-golfed version anymore. But I'll write it properly with 20 chars variable names as soon as I decide to stop shrinking it.

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (175)

```
function t(e,v,f){if(!v&&v!=''){v=e.data||'';for(c in f=e.childNodes)v+=t(f[c]);return v}else{ while(c=e.lastChild)e.removeChild(c);e.appendChild(document.createTextNode(v))}}
```

I have significantly less morality than @dystroy, so I didn't bother with **var**. I did have to scope **f** though, and I did it somewhat cleverly.

That said, our answers are pretty similar, and I'm not sure there's much of a better way to go about it.

With collection recognition **(173)**:

```
function t(e,v){if(!v&&v!=''){v=e.data||'';for each(c in e.childNodes)v+=t(c);return v}else{ while(c=e.lastChild)e.removeChild(c);e.appendChild(document.createTextNode(v))}}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 143 bytes

```javascript
t=(e,h)=>h?.sub?[...e.children].map(c=>e.removeChild(c))&&e.appendChild(document.createTextNode(h)):(e.data||'')+[...e.childNodes].map(c=>t(c))
```